# How to import bootstrap in visual studio sharepoint/office webpart?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, bootstrap-4, web-parts

I have created a SharePoint webpart in visual studio and i want to use bootstrap in the webpart. How do i import or link bootstrap in the webpart?

```
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> 
<%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AdminDashBoardUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="Portal_Webparts.AdminDashBoard.AdminDashBoardUserControl" %>

<%-- Here i was tring to link it but i dont know if its the way its done. After creating the webpart this is only what i did--%>

<%@ Import importableModuleLoader from '@microsoft/sp-module-loader'; %>
<%@ Import importableModuleLoader.loadCss('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css') %>
```

Answer (score 0):

To reference bootstrap css in your webpart, try.

```
<style type='text/css'>    
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css");
 </style>
```

[image]

Comment: i tried referencing using the link that you provided and placed a navigation bar and this error was displayed at the top of the page ```Error loading navigation: TermStore not found (Correlation ID: c3c03b9f-4548-408c-9d8b-8345355ea085)``` and nothing was diaplyed.

Comment: The error related to your webpart logic, not caused by bootstrap, check ULS log for detailed error.

Comment: I haven't seen any content in your webpart, so it'll render as blank, bootstrap just apply CSS to your HTML DOMs, you could insert sample text or div/p etc. content into your webpart to check the webpart render.

Comment: I figured what i was doing wrong thanks. Will it be the same for importing js files